# Changing an object properties in Javascript via Chrome console

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I currently have a single order provided by a JSON file. I cannot seem to access it's properties in the console via Google Chrome.

When there are multiple orders, how can I change that current objects properties if I am unaware of its array number?

For example, how can I change the seatcount(bkor_seatcount) number to 9 in the console and later via a method?

[Console Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/585Jq.jpg)

Comment: Did you try simple assigning a global variable (reference) to the object, then accessing it from the console?

Comment: Can you give me an example please?

Comment: I have now added an ID to that Seatcount element with ```var seatcount = document.getElementById('seatcounter')``` and then doing ```seatcount = 10;``` but nothing changes on the left side of the screen(that current object/order)

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. Use Chrome's powerful debugger instead of `console.log`. You appear to have used `console.log` to dump out the content of a variable somewhere in your code. That's useful sometimes, but usually rather than stumbling around in the dark with a `console.log` torch, you're much better off using the debugger to turn on the lights. In the Sources tab, locate the code where you're logging, and set a breakpoint. Run the code until it hits the breakpoint. Then, you can change the value of any in-scope variable from the console and click the arrow to allow the code to continue running.

   Details on using the dev tools [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/).
2. If for some reason that's not going to work for you, you can usually right-click the thing that you logged (The `v [Object]` bit) and choose "Store as Global Variable" from the menu. Chrome will automatically create a global with a name like `temp1` which you can then access.